# How to manipultate intervals in a three column table

Tags: awk, command

I have a file, part of which I am posting you below after sorting:

```
area1   38896   39876
area1   39532   40521
area1   55975   56958
area1   73070   74098
area1   79689   79934
area2   43757   46798
area2   44055   47111
area2   54208   54354
area2   57000   59336
area2   69391   72882
area3   49621   50967
area3   49946   51322
area3   53044   53505
area3   65205   66473
area3   66888   68294
```

My target is to have one interval of these areas by subtracting the last set of coordinates minus the first one, for each area. 
By the definition, the internal of 2 points in the Cartesian system is `d= sqrt( (X2 –x1)^2 +(y2 –y1)^2 )` Initially, I tried to find the solution with bedtool but I didn’t find anything related to my case.

My desired output :

`d area1 =sqrt{ (79689 -38896) ^2  + (79934-39876)  ^2}`

`d area2 =sqrt{ (69391-43757 ) ^2  + (72882-46798)^2}`  etc

I write this prompt:

```
Cat myfile | sort -k1,1 -k2,2n |sort -V  |awk 'NR %5==1 {print $1,$2,$3 } NR%5==0 {print $1,$2,$3}'|awk {for (i=2; i<=$i ;i++) {a[i]=sqrt((p[i]*p[i])+($i*$1))}  } { for(i=2; i<=$i ;i++) {p[i]=$i;}  }  /[0-9]/{ for (i in a) {printf "%s ",a[i]};print "";print "" }
```

But I failed on doing what I want. Does anyone have an idea of how to handle it?

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/help/formatting for how to format your code, sample input, and expected output legibly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not the most optimized solution but this should work.

```
sort -k1,1 -k2,2n -k3,3n < your_file_name | \
awk '{if(length(x1[$1])==0) x1[$1]=$2; x2[$1]=$2;\
if(length(y1[$1])==0) y1[$1]=$3; y2[$1]=$3;} END \
{for (i in x1) print i, sqrt((x2[i]-x1[i])^2+(y2[i]-y1[i])^2)}'
```

Explanation:

```
sort -k1,1 -k2,2n -k3,3n  --  Sort data and numeric sort for column 2 and 3
if(length(x1[$1])==0) x1[$1]=$2; x2[$1]=$2;--  Use associate array to get first value for each area name 
END -- Loop through all records
```

Demo :

```
$sort -k1,1 -k2,2n -k3,3n < area.txt | awk '{if(length(x1[$1])==0) x1[$1]=$2; x2[$1]=$2;\
if(length(y1[$1])==0) y1[$1]=$3; y2[$1]=$3;} END \
{for (i in x1) print i, sqrt((x2[i]-x1[i])^2+(y2[i]-y1[i])^2)}'
area1 57172.7
area2 36571.5
area3 24461.7
$cat area.txt 
area1 38896 39876
area1 39532 40521
area1 55975 56958
area1 73070 74098
area1 79689 79934
area2 43757 46798
area2 44055 47111
area2 54208 54354
area2 57000 59336
area2 69391 72882
area3 49621 50967
area3 49946 51322
area3 53044 53505
area3 65205 66473
area3 66888 68294
$

$sort -k1,1 -k2,2n -k3,3n < area.txt | awk '{if(length(x1[$1])==0) x1[$1]=$2; x2[$1]=$2;\
if(length(y1[$1])==0) y1[$1]=$3; y2[$1]=$3;} END \
{for (i in x1) print i, x2[i], x1[i], y2[i], y1[i]}'
area1 79689 38896 79934 39876
area2 69391 43757 72882 46798
area3 66888 49621 68294 50967
$
```